# Conceptual difference between ket and bra vectors in layman's terms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, linear-algebra, notation

From the relation $\langle a|b \rangle = \langle b|a \rangle ^*$ it can be seen that we can get same inner product by "swapping vectors" in Hilbert space and taking complex conjugate of the resulting complex scalar. So it seems that ket and bra vectors are "two sides of the same story". Then how bra vector $\langle a|$ is *conceptually* different from ket vector $|a \rangle$ if both belong to the same Hilbert vector space ? To me, I see just one principal difference is that ket is column vector and bra - row vector. That's it. Are there any more "radical" differences ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149302/discussion-on-question-by-agnius-vasiliauskas-conceptual-difference-between-ket); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then how bra vector $\langle a|$ is *conceptually* different from ket vector $|a \rangle$ if both belong to the same Hilbert vector space?

Bras don't belong to "the same" Hilbert vector space as kets. They belong to a different vector space, which is described in terms of "blabage" as a "dual vector space." But if you don't like such "blabage" just think of it as another complex vector space (which happens to have the same number of dimension when the ket space is finite dimensional). I'll explain with less blabage below.

> To me, I see just one principal difference is that ket is column vector and bra - row vector. That's it.

When you *represent* a ket as a column vector, e.g.:
$$
|\uparrow\rangle \to \left(\begin{matrix}1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right)\;,
$$
then, yes, a bra is represented as a row vector, e.g.:
$$
\langle\uparrow| \to \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)\;,
$$

These "row vectors" (row matrices) are *representations* in the same way that a square matrix can be a *representation* of a linear operator. A matrix is not an operator, a matrix is a representation of an operator. Similarly, the column/row matrices representing kets/bras is a convenient way to work with bras and kets just like the square matrix representation of an operator is a convenient way to work with operators.

---

> Note. Please explain it without wiki style "blabage" about dual vector spaces and linear maps, because after reading it still is unclear to me how this dual space maps to the general Hilbert space, where all action is going on.

You understand that kets are vectors in a Hilbert space. You can think of a vector in a Hilbert space like a point in an N-dimensional space, or like an ordered set of N complex numbers.

Obviously, you can create a function of $N$ complex numbers like, for example:
$$
f_1(a,b,c,...,z) = |a|^2 + b + 2z\;,
$$
or whatever.

You can also write down a function of a ket ($|\psi\rangle = \psi_1|1\rangle + \psi_2|2\rangle+\ldots$, since a ket is basically just a collection of N complex numbers), like, for example:
$$
f_2(|\psi\rangle) = |\psi_1|^2 + \psi_2 +2\psi_N
$$

The above functions are non-linear, but obviously we can also write down a *linear* function of a ket like:
$$
f_3(|\psi\rangle) = \psi_1 + 7\psi_2 + 15\psi_3\;.
$$

Ok, lets call a general *linear* function (of a ket) "$f$." Since the function is linear we can write:
$$
f(a|\psi\rangle+b|\chi\rangle) = af(|\psi\rangle)+bf(|\chi\rangle)\;.
$$

**The function $f$ defines a bra:**
$$
f(|\psi\rangle)\equiv \langle f|\psi\rangle\;.
$$

The linearity of $f$ means that, for $|\xi\rangle = a|\psi\rangle + b |\chi\rangle$:
$$
\langle f|\xi\rangle
=\langle f|\left(a|\psi\rangle+b|\chi\rangle\right)
=a\langle f|\psi\rangle + b\langle f|\chi\rangle\;,
$$
just like we have grown accustomed to when working with bras and kets.

---

Since there are lots of different linear functions of kets, there are lots of different bras.

It's helpful to look at some examples.

For example, suppose some function $g$ is zero regardless of what ket is the input:
$$
g(|\psi\rangle) = 0\qquad\text{for all }|\psi\rangle\;.
$$
We then say the bra is zero:
$$
\langle g| = 0\;.
$$

For example, suppose two functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ always give the same output regardless of what ket is the input:
$$
g_1(|\psi\rangle) = g_2(|\psi\rangle)\qquad\text{for all }|\psi\rangle\;.
$$
We then say the bras are equal:
$$
\langle g_1| = \langle g_2|\;.
$$

Further explanation of bra vectors can be found in Messiah's quantum mechanics textbook, volume 1, chapter VII, section 3 (titled "Dual Space. 'Bra' Vectors").

---

Consider an example for a two-dimensional ket space, such as the space of a spin 1/2 particle, ignoring spatial position.

In this case, we can pick two basis states:
$$
|\uparrow\rangle
$$
and
$$
|\downarrow\rangle\;.
$$

And in the "dual space" (sorry for blabaging) we can pick two "basis functions"
$$
u(|\psi\rangle) = \psi_\uparrow
$$
and
$$
d(|\psi\rangle) = \psi_\downarrow\;,
$$
where I'm denoting a general ket $|\psi\rangle$ in the 2d space as $|\psi\rangle = \psi_\uparrow|\uparrow\rangle + \psi_\downarrow|\downarrow\rangle$. So the function "u" just picks out the (complex) up-spin coefficient and the function "d" just picks out the (complex) down-spin coefficient.

We denote these functions as bras, respectively:
$$
u(\cdot)\equiv\langle\uparrow|
$$
and
$$
d(\cdot)\equiv\langle\downarrow|
$$

Obviously any linear function:
$$
f(|\psi\rangle) = \alpha \psi_\uparrow + \beta \psi_\downarrow
$$
can be written as a linear combination of the basis functions:
$$
f(|\psi\rangle) = \alpha u(|\psi\rangle) + \beta d(|\psi\rangle)\;.
$$
$$
=a\langle \uparrow|\psi\rangle + b \langle \downarrow|\psi\rangle\;,
$$
so we see that for this finite dimensional Hilbert space of kets the "dual" bra space has the same number of dimensions.

---

To make a connection to the "row vector" representation of bras, we can simply note that any linear function of a N-dimensional ket can be described by setting N complex constant parameters. Just like how, when we  choose a basis any ket can be described by setting N complex constant parameters.

An N-dimensional bra, as represented by a row matrix
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}a & b & \ldots & z\end{matrix}\right)
$$
corresponds to a *linear* function:
$$
\zeta(|\psi\rangle) = a\psi_1+b\psi_2+\ldots+z\psi_N
=\left(\begin{matrix}a & b & \ldots & z\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}\psi_1 \\ \psi_2 \\ \ldots \\ \psi_N\end{matrix}\right)
$$
$$
\equiv \langle \zeta|\psi\rangle\;.
$$

The fact that we are only interested in *linear* functions of kets means that we have a wonderful concrete representation in terms of row matrices. This is the same reason we have a wonderful concrete representation of *linear* operators in terms of square matrices.

Comment: This answer is perfect +1.

Comment: Great, thanks @Cerise

Comment: What does basis function $u(|\psi\rangle) = \psi_\uparrow$ do ? Returns spin-up state ket vector or something different ?

Comment: It's a function that takes kets as input and returns a complex number as output (it does not output a ket, it outputs a complex number). This particular function returns the spin-up *coefficient* (a complex number that I have denoted by $\psi_\uparrow$) of a ket.

Comment: So, ket vectors stores in Hilbert space unidentified complex parameters and bra vectors - "weights" or coefficients of a linear polynomials in dual space with whom kets in Hilbert space can be processed ? And applying linear polynomial to a ket vector is equivalent to an inner product between bra and ket vectors, right ? That's why we can write either $\langle f|x \rangle$, which represents function application to a ket, or $(f,x)$ which represents inner product, but basically it's the sides of same story, right ?

Comment: That sounds about right to me.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer**: As the others stated in their comments, the "blablage" you are talking about is really the answer to your question. Mathematics, and specifically advanced Mathematics, is not intuitive at all. Quantum mechanics is not Lego toys science.

Now let me try to give you a more intuitive "feeling" of what such "blablage" tries to tell you.

The first problem is that what you state is false: the vector (ket) $|\alpha\rangle$ belongs to the Hilbert vector space $\mathcal{H}$ but the dual vector (bra) $\langle \alpha|$ does NOT belong to the vector space $\mathcal{H}$, rather it belongs to the dual vector space $\mathcal{H}^*$

They are both vector spaces, but they are NOT the same vector spaces. "The general Hilbert space where all action is going on" is false, there is no general Hilbert space.

So what is the difference? It is simple.

Vectors are state vectors, containing all the informations about your system. The space $\mathcal{H}$ then is the space containing all the vectors which describe a system state.

Dual vectors are not state vectors, they are linear functions $\phi(h), h \in \mathcal{H}$ (a generalisation of $y=mx$) which act ON state vectors $h$. The space $\mathcal{H}^*$ is then the space which contains all the linear functions on vectors belonging to $\mathcal{H}$.
The space of this functions also has a vector space structure, since you can add/subtract and scale such linear functions.

> Think of this as a generalisation of $y_1 + y_2 = (m_1 + m_2)x$ and $m'y = (m'm)x$

The thing that let you think that "all the action happens in a general Hilbert space" is due to a very important theorem, the [Riesz Representation Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).

This theorem states that it is possible to associate to a linear function  on vectors $\phi(h) \in \mathcal{H}^*$, a unique vector $|g\rangle \in \mathcal{H}$ such that $\forall |\alpha\rangle \in \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \phi(\alpha) = |g\rangle \cdot |\alpha\rangle = \langle g| |\alpha\rangle$

The identification then is:
$$\langle g| \in \mathcal{H}^* = |g\rangle \cdot \_\_ $$

Comment: So, if I understand correctly Riesz enabled mapping between these different vector spaces by using complex conjugate property of complex numbers domain, i.e. $ \mathcal{H^*} \mapsto \mathcal{H} ~\text{as}~ \langle g | \alpha \rangle  = (g^\dagger,\alpha) $ ?

Comment: Yes, fundamentally that's the deal. You need to satisfy some properties being an infinite dimensional space, but that is the point

Comment: You can map each element in $\mathcal{H}^*$ to a specific vector $g$ in $\mathcal{H}$ such that the action of the element in  $\mathcal{H}^*$ on a vector $h$ is just the Hermitian product between the vector $g$ and the vector $h$

Answer (score 2):

Call your Hilbert space $H$. Let's first assume a positive-definite sesquilinear function $H^2\mapsto\Bbb C$ denoted $\langle a,\,b\rangle$: an inner product, in other words.

As @hft notes, we can't do entirely without the blabage you mentioned, but I'll try to make it more accessible. We start by noting - proof is an exercise - that the linear forms$^\dagger$ from $H$ to $\Bbb C$ are precisely the functions of the form $x\mapsto\langle y,\,x\rangle=\langle x,\,y\rangle^\ast$. The set of such forms is a vector space over $\Bbb C$ in its own right. This provides an easy identification of which of the "original" vectors should label each such form.

We can then write $\langle y,\,x\rangle$ as $\langle y|x\rangle$, and construe it as mapping from vectors living in different copies of $H$, and call one of these a dual vector space. For some reason, the vectors in this space are called covectors rather than dual vectors; at any rate, we say $\langle x|$ is a covector to $|x\rangle$. So when you ask how $\langle x|$ is conceptually different from $|x\rangle$, it's better to ask what makes one covector earn the same label as a specific vector in the original space. But we've covered that already.

$^\dagger$ This is in the physicist's convention, in which the inner product is linear in its rightmost argument; the mathematician's convention says it's anti-linear in the rightmost argument, but then the antilinear forms are as I've described. Admittedly we normally fix this subtlety by instead continuing to work with linear forms, thus switching the left/right roles of each variable; but then we'd have to write some of the algebra all over again.

Comment: The thing I don't understand about covectors, is that you can map N linear functions to the _same_ ket vector $|x\rangle$ and get N complex scalars as a result. Then question arises,- which bra vector is _truly_ a covector to specific ket vector $x$, or **all of them** which can map $|x\rangle$ to some complex numbers are covectors ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas The covector of $|x\rangle$, denoted $\langle x|$, is the function $y\mapsto\langle x,\,y\rangle$. Is your question about whether the function so defined depends on which inner product we chose for the original vector space?

Comment: Yes, sort of it. If we can define many inner products with same ket and all of them are "covectors" to the input ket vector, then What is the general rule of which covector of $|x\rangle$ ket will be used ? Or there is no such rule and required bras are used by-demand of specific need ? Sorry, I can't formulate my question better, because my understanding of bra-kets is vague and if I will have a decent question,- then it will be a $\frac 12$ of answer, because you find something fast only in case you know where to look for.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Crucial points: (i) The choice of inner product isn't unique. (ii) People usually fix this choice throughout their discussion of $H$. (iii) Which function is dual to a given vector depends on that choice. (iv) The choice fixes which functions are dual to which vectors. (v) Each vector always ends up dual to a covector given the same label. (vi) We can use this labelling to summarize the inner product with a Hermitian positive-definite matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Focus on the physics, then move into more abstract territory as needed.

I think the physical way to get into the concept is the fact that in the theory, $\langle y|x\rangle$ represents the amplitude for state $|x\rangle$ to collapse into state $|y\rangle$. So, physically, $\langle y|$ models some sort of filter, a polarizer for example. A horizontal polarizer, modeled as  $\langle h|$, finds the amplitude of the horizontally polarized component $|h\rangle$ from a state of mixed polarization. In the quantum domain, $\langle h|$ is not a complete model instrument: you still need to square the amplitude to get a probability, similar to the fact that you need both a polarizer and a detector to make a polarimeter.

This idea isn't restricted to quantum theory. It may be easier to explain other linear processes to physics colleagues in familiar Dirac notation (done that). A [matched filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter) $\langle s| $ optimally estimates the amplitude $a$ of a signal $ |s\rangle $ in data $(a\ |s\rangle+|n \rangle)$, where $|n\rangle$ is Gaussian white noise.